# Circular UIImageView on UITableViewCell not working on first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, calayer

In my messages section of my app, I have a tableview loading the text and the image of the user who said it. I would like a circular image view for the image, and have written code to do that, but when I first load it, the visible cells still have a square image. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.messagesTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"messageCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"messageCell"];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kUserImageData"]];

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.bounds.size.width / 2;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    NSLog(@"%f", cell.imageView.bounds.size.height);

   return cell;
}
```

Also, something weird is that the NSLog for the first few cells (that have square images) is 0.000000. I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.bounds.size.width / 2;

imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

hope this will work.